# collectd: What are the units of the measurements captured by the disk, interface, irq, and swap_io plugins?

Tags: collectd

What are the units of the measurements captured by the `disk`, `interface`, `irq`, and `swap_io` collectd plugins?

I'm comparing collectd 5 running on one machine with collectd 4 running on another, and trying to configure them both so they capture the same metrics.

`disk` reports fractional floats on collectd 5 (KiB?), integers on 4 (bytes).

`interface` is fractional floats on collectd 5 (KiB?), integer on 4 (bytes).

`irq` is apparently percentages on collectd 5, cumulative jiffies(?) on 4.

`swap_io` is floats (with an occasional 'nan') on collectd 5, integer on 4.

Additionally, the cpu plugin is supposed, according to the collectd wiki, to capture jiffies when `ValuesPercentage` is false and both `ReportByCpu` and `ReportByState` are true (their defaults). The collectd 4 cpu plugin does not offer these options and measures in jiffies. I set the collectd.conf of the version 5 instance to the settings I just mentioned (even explicitly setting defaults) and...it stubbornly continues to report percentages instead of jiffies!

**Update:** After taking a close look at the code for collectd 5, it has become clear that *the collectd wiki is lying*: when `ValuesPercentage` is false and both `ReportByCpu` and `ReportByState` are true, the `cpu` plugin reports **rates of change** and not cumulative jiffies (as in collectd 4).

Further **Update**: I had misinterpreted the collectd 4 behaviour for `swap_io`. Turns out the `swap` metrics are in bytes while `swap_io` is in pages (and you can't configure that), so the correct collectd 5 setting is `ReportBytes = false` and not `ReportBytes = true`. That's one less discrepancy.

**collectd.conf** for version 4:

```
# We're running collectd 4.10.9
# FQDNLookup since 4.3, became true by default with 5.0
FQDNLookup false
##
## Interval (in seconds) at which to query values.
## Starting with 5.4.3, this may be overridden on a per-plugin basis.
Interval 60
##
## Client part
##
## Logging (only one allowed)
##
# syslog since 4.0
LoadPlugin syslog
<Plugin syslog>
  LogLevel info
</Plugin>
##
## Inputs
##
# cpu since 1.3
LoadPlugin cpu

# df since 3.6
LoadPlugin df
<Plugin df>
  FSType tmpfs
  IgnoreSelected true
# ReportByDevice since 4.8
  ReportByDevice true
# ReportInodes false
# ReportReserved false by default; the option became true and was removed with version 5
  ReportReserved true
# ValuesAbsolute, ValuesPercentage starting with collectd 5.4
</Plugin>

# disk since 1.5
LoadPlugin disk

# interface since 1.0
LoadPlugin interface

# irq since 4.0
LoadPlugin irq

# load since 1.0 (not sure about ReportRelative)
LoadPlugin load
<Plugin load>
  ReportRelative true
</Plugin>

# memory since 1.0
# No options for 4.10
LoadPlugin memory

# nfs since 3.3
LoadPlugin nfs

# processes since 3.2
LoadPlugin processes
<Plugin processes>
# ProcessMatch since 4.5
  ProcessMatch "all" "(.*)"
</Plugin>

# protocols since 4.7
LoadPlugin protocols

# swap since 2.1
# No options for 4.10
LoadPlugin swap
<Plugin swap>
# 4.10 reports swap I/O in pages (and cannot be configured otherwise)
# 4.10 reports swap cached/free/used in bytes
</Plugin>

# tcpconns since 4.2
LoadPlugin tcpconns

# thermal since 4.5
LoadPlugin thermal

# uptime since 4.7
LoadPlugin uptime
##
## Server part
##
## Output (only one allowed)
##
# csv since 4.0
LoadPlugin csv
<Plugin csv>
  DataDir "/var/collectd/csv"
# StoreRates since 4.3
  StoreRates false
</Plugin>

# write_graphite since 5.1
# write_http since 4.8
```

**collectd.conf** for version 5:

```
# We are running collectd 5.4.0.git

# FQDNLookup since 4.3, became true by default with 5.0
FQDNLookup false

# Interval (in seconds) at which to query values. This may be overwritten on
# a per-plugin basis by using the 'Interval' option of the LoadPlugin block.
# This capability was announced with version 5.2 but became functional
# only with 5.4.3.
Interval 60

# Logging
# syslog since 4.0
LoadPlugin syslog
<Plugin syslog>
    LogLevel info
</Plugin>

# LoadPlugin section
# cpu since 1.3
LoadPlugin cpu
<Plugin cpu>
#   ReportByCpu true
#   ReportByState true
# ValuesPercentage starting with collectd 5.5
#   ValuesPercentage true
# ValuesPercentage false forces measurements in jiffies/second when both
# ReportByCpu and ReportByState are true (the defaults); collectd 4 does
# not do time derivation (and time derivation cannot be turned off in 5)
    ValuesPercentage false
</Plugin>

# df since 3.6
LoadPlugin df
<Plugin df>
    FSType rootfs
    FSType sysfs
    FSType proc
    FSType devtmpfs
    FSType devpts
    FSType tmpfs
    FSType fusectl
    FSType cgroup
    IgnoreSelected true

# ReportByDevice since 4.8
    ReportByDevice true

# ValuesAbsolute, ValuesPercentage since 5.4
# ValuesAbsolute for reporting in bytes (true by default)
#   ValuesAbsolute true
    ValuesPercentage false
</Plugin>

# disk since 1.5
LoadPlugin disk

# irq since 4.0
LoadPlugin irq

# load since 1.0 (not sure about ReportRelative)
LoadPlugin load
<Plugin load>
    ReportRelative true
</Plugin>

# memory since 1.0
# No options for 4.10
LoadPlugin memory
<Plugin memory>
    ValuesAbsolute true
    ValuesPercentage false
</Plugin>

# nfs since 3.3
LoadPlugin nfs

# processes since 3.2
LoadPlugin processes
<Plugin processes>
# ProcessMatch since 4.5
    ProcessMatch "all" "(.*)"
</Plugin>

# protocols since 4.7
LoadPlugin protocols

# swap since 2.1
# No options for 4.10
LoadPlugin swap
<Plugin swap>
    ReportByDevice true
#   ReportIO true
# ReportBytes is false by default; when false, swap I/O is in pages
# 4.10 reports swap I/O in pages (and cannot be configured otherwise)
    ReportBytes false
    ValuesAbsolute true
    ValuesPercentage false
# 4.10 reports swap cached/free/used in bytes, swap_io in/out in pages
</Plugin>

# tcpconns since 4.2
LoadPlugin tcpconns

# thermal since 4.5
LoadPlugin thermal

# thermal since 4.7
LoadPlugin uptime

# Server part
LoadPlugin write_graphite
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Node "node-graphite-1">
    Host "192.168.1.170"
    Port "1111"
    Protocol "tcp"
    EscapeCharacter "_"
    AlwaysAppendDS true
    SeparateInstances false
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

disk reports cumulative operations (ops) and also cumulative bytes (Io).

interface reports cumulative packet and error counts on the one hand, and cumulative bytes on the other.

swap_io reports cumulative operations.

Can you post your exact full config please, so we can troubleshoot your collectd5 CPU config?

Comment: `disk_merged.read` reports fractional values such as the 0.0 to 31.8 range with collectd 5. Collectd 4 reports whole numbers, ranging up to 24000 or so. I can't compare the numbers directly because collectd 5 and collectd 4 are observing completely different systems. What are the units? Thousands? Blocks of 1024 bytes? Something else?

There is no `lo` output, just `merged`, `octets`, `ops`, and `time`.

Similarly, `interface` reports fractional `rx` values such as 135417.2. There is no such thing as a fractional packet, is there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that turned out to be a simple, stupid mistake. The `csv` plugin used on one side has a default for `StoreRates` of `false`, while the `graphite` plugin used on the other has a default of `true`, and that was why some (but not all) metrics were integer (cumulative counts) while others were floats (rates of increase).